# Question about arbitrary set intersections.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Consider that we have $\{A_i \mid i\in I\}$ some indexed family of sets. We know that, pairwise, $A_i\cap A_j\neq\emptyset$ for all $i,j\in I$. I have read that $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}A_i\neq\emptyset$ is a result of this. I am wondering, if we change the setup slightly, will this same principle still hold?

That is, instead assume we know nothing about the intersections of $A_i\cap A_j$. Then, consider $B$ such that $B\cap A_i\neq\emptyset$ for all $i\in I$. Is it still true that $\bigcap\limits_{i\in I}B\cap A_i\neq\emptyset$? Or is there a different formulation here?

Comment: Where did you get your first claim? Take $A_n=\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid |x|>n\}$.

Comment: For the first part, consider three closed halfs of the same circle, $120^\circ$ apart.

Answer (score 4):

It is wrong at the very beginning. Consider the family $\{A_1, A_2, A_3\}$ of sets, where $A_1=\{1,2\}$, $A_2=\{2,3\}$, and $A_3=\{1,3\}$. Clearly, for any $i,j=1,2,3$, $A_i\cap A_j \neq \emptyset$. However, $\bigcap_{i=1}^3 A_i = \emptyset$.

///////////////////////////

For the second part, it is also false. For example, let $A_1, A_2, A_3$ be defined in above and let $B=\{1,2,3\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Neither statement is true without additional assumptions. Here are counter-examples where $I = \Bbb{N}$ and $A_i \subseteq \Bbb{N}$:

1. Let $A_i = \{ m : \Bbb{N} \mid m \ge i \}$. Then $A_i \cap A_j \neq \emptyset$ for all $i, j \in \Bbb{N}$, but $\bigcap_i A_i = \emptyset$. (This shows that the first statement fails in general even when the $A_i$ form a chain, i.e., for any $i, j$, either $A_i \subseteq A_j$ or $A_j \subseteq A_i$.)
2. Let $A_i = \{i\}$ and $B = \Bbb{N}$. Then $B \cap A_i \neq \emptyset$ for all $i \in \Bbb{N}$, but $\bigcap_i(B \cap A_i) = \emptyset$